# Why doesn't Java allow the use of a ternary operator here?

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error, conditional-operator

Instead of typing :

```
if (Math.random() < .5) {
    System.out.println("toto");
} else {
    System.out.println("tata");
}
```

I would find it useful, and logical, to type instead :

```
Math.random() < .5 ? System.out.println("toto") : System.out.println("tata");
```

However, I get the error `not a statement`. I don't understand how this is an issue.

Comment: The conditional operator is for evaluating expressions, not executing statements. `System.out.println("todo")` is not an expression: it doesn't have any value. The `if` statement is for executing statements, so use that.

Comment: You can do this:
`String answer = Math.random() < .5 ? "toto" : "tata" ;
 System.out.println(answer); 
`

Comment: Or in one line: `System.out.println(Math.random() < .5 ? "toto" : "tata");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the ternary operator assigns a value to a variable. Change it to:

```
String toPrint = Math.random() < .5 ? "toto" : "tata";
System.out.println(toPrint);
```